# jQuery fadeOut siblings if visible

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to figure out how to target all `siblings` and fade them out, before fading in the element that's being targeted.

```
$('#MyDiv').siblings(':visible').not('h2').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#MyDiv').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

The `:visible` selector isn't working, but in theory it should, right? The issue is the `complete` event is being run immediately because there are some siblings that are already hidden.

This should be a simple solution for someone ... I think I've been staring at this for too long and I'm missing something simple.

Comment: works fine for me - http://jsbin.com/zutusuwono/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: The issue is that some siblings are and some aren't visible ... so, for the ones that aren't, the "complete" executes immediately.

Comment: Could you post your HTML, i don't see any issue> https://jsfiddle.net/vxvfzo1s/1/

Comment: Have the non-visible elements been made invisible through a jQuery method? Some edge case quirks with [the visible selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/venitatome/edit?html,css,js,output - some are hidden, some are visible

Answer (score 0):

OK - Maybe try a different approach? In this instance the "complete" only fires once.

```js
$('#div3').fadeOut(500);
$('#div1').fadeOut(500);

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#div1').siblings(':visible').not('h2')
    .fadeOut(500).promise().done(
      function() {
        $('#div1').fadeIn();
      }
    );
}, 1500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="div1">
    <p>Div1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <p>Div2</p>
  </div>
  <h2>H2</h2>
  <div id="div3">
    <p>Div3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div4">
    <p>Div4</p>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The issue is that some siblings are and some aren't visible ... so, for the ones that aren't, the "complete" executes immediately.

Comment: OK - sorry I missed that initially. Maybe the approach above will work for you...in my test it only fires once.